# runBlocking() doesn't block the thread in this situation

Tags: multithreading, kotlin, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines

I am confused about runBlocking() and coroutineScope(). I have been reading a lot about this but I still get confused. I know that runBlocking() blocks the thread and coroutineScope() suspends the coroutine but I don't clearly understand what it means.

In this example, it prints A and then B. However, runBlocking() should block the thread until all it's code finishes. So A shouldn't be printed while the thread is blocked by runBlocking(). It should print B and then A.

```
runBlocking {
        launch {
            delay(1000L)
            println("A")
        }
        runBlocking {
            delay(3000L)
            println("B")
        }
    }
```

In this other code, it prints B and then A.

```
runBlocking {
        launch {
            delay(1000L)
            println("A")
        }
        runBlocking {
            Thread.sleep(3000L)
            println("B")
        }
    }
```

Thread.sleep() really blocks the thread and A cannot be printed while the thread is blocked.

What does it means to block the thread using runBlocking() if coroutines in this thread can be executed while the thread is blocked?

What's the difference between runBlocking() and coroutineScope() if this code has the same behaviour as the first one?

```
runBlocking {
        launch {
            delay(1000L)
            println("A")
        }
        coroutineScope {
            delay(3000L)
            println("B")
        }
    }
```

Comment: "What's the difference between runBlocking() and coroutineScope()?", `runBlocking` is a normal function that creates new coroutine, `coroutineScope` is a suspened function that creates new coroutine scope. From `runBlocking` docs: _**This function should not be used from a coroutine.** It is designed to bridge regular blocking code to libraries that are written in suspending style, to be used in main functions and in tests._, just don't use it like that.

Comment: @IR42 It's true that runBlocking should not be used from a coroutine, but that doesn't mean it can't. Using runBlocking like this is a very succinct way to test what "runBlocking blocks the current thread" means. But there are other ways to demonstrate the same question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know why your first example isn't working the way the [runBlocking documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/run-blocking.html) would seem to indicate. When I try it, instead of printing "A" first, it doesn't print "A" at all! Maybe, as others said, it's because runBlocking is not supposed to run from within a coroutine (but it's not forbidden, or else an exception should be thrown, and the behavior shouldn't violate the documentation).

However this may shed light on your question. I reimplemented your example without the outer `runBlocking`, using `lifecycleScope.launch()` for the "A" coroutine (you can also use `GlobalScope.launch()`):

```kotlin
    private fun testCoroutines() {
        Log.d(TAG, "start on thread ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
        this.lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
            Log.d(TAG, "A in launch: ${threadAndJob()}")
            delay(1000L)
            Log.d(TAG, "A end launch: ${threadAndJob()}")
        }
        runBlocking {
            Log.d(TAG, "B in runBlocking: ${threadAndJob()}")
            delay(3000L)
            Log.d(TAG, "B end runBlocking: ${threadAndJob()}")
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "finish on thread ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
    }

    private fun CoroutineScope.threadAndJob() =
        "thread ${Thread.currentThread().name}; job ${coroutineContext.job}"
```

Now we should be able to see whether another coroutine can run on the main thread while `runBlocking` is supposed to be blocking it.
And we can do this without using `runBlocking` inside a coroutine.

The output:

```
    start on thread main
    B in runBlocking: thread main; job BlockingCoroutine{Active}@9b89588
    B end runBlocking: thread main; job BlockingCoroutine{Active}@9b89588
    finish on thread main
    A in launch: thread main; job StandaloneCoroutine{Active}@a953b46
    A end launch: thread main; job StandaloneCoroutine{Active}@a953b46
```

This log output shows us that even though the B coroutine inside of `runBlocking` was suspended for 3 seconds, the A coroutine launched on the main thread was unable to run until after the `runBlocking` code had finished. Which confirms that the main thread was really blocked during `runBlocking`, as you understood from the [runBlocking documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/run-blocking.html).

Answer (score -1):

The entire idea of using a runBlocking is when you need your code inside your `runblocking` thread to be executed at once, when you call `runblocking` : it means "block until whatever is inside this block is finished" when you call a parent `runblocking` it will just block until your code inside that is executed, but in case of `coroutinescope` you can always map that to a specific thread mode. I suggest you to clear your basics with coroutines first!

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.